# Proove that $(c,\omega)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, stokes-theorem

Let (i) $c\in B_r(M),\omega \in Z^r(M)$ or (ii) $\omega\in B^r(M),c\in Z_r(M).$
Show in both cases $$(c,\omega)=0.$$
My approach to prove (ii),
$$(c,\omega)=\int_c\omega$$ if we use Stokes theorem $$\int_c \omega=\int_{\partial c} \psi $$ where we can let $\omega=d \psi$ because $\omega\in B^r(M)$. Since $c\in Z_r(M)$ we have $\partial c =\emptyset$ which proves 
$$(c,\omega)=0.$$

How do I prove this for the case given by (i).

Comment: Same idea as in approach ii:  If $c  = \partial c'$, then $\int_c \omega = \int_{\partial c'}  \omega = \int_{c'} d\omega$.  But $d\omega = ?$